# Problema com SQLite.Net.Interop

Tags: sqlite, xamarin-forms

Estou tentando usar o namespace SQLite.Net.Interop para usar a classe ISQLitePlatform mas o package "SQLite.Net PCL" está como descontinuado.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma alternativa para resolver esse problema.

Meu projeto está em Xamarin.Forms e preciso saber qual plataforma para poder obter o caminho certo de armazenamento do aquivo de banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema um tempo atrás, consegui resolver utilizando [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl)

A atualização foi relativamente tranquila.

Pa obter o caminho eu utilizo:

```
var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, _fileName);

var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
return connection;
```